# How to enable flash on NWJS?

Tags: node.js, nw.js

How to enable flash on NWJS? my current package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "name": "NAME",
  "description": "NAME.",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "chromium-args": "--ppapi-flash-path=plugins/pepflashplayer.dll --ppapi-flash-version=20.0.0.306",
  "webkit": {
    "plugin": true
  }
}
```

and i have lib in APP/plugins/pepflashplayer.dll but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future users: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Use%20Flash%20Plugin/#using-flash-plugin

**Note:** i don't think you need chromium-args to do this, but anyway you can check your plugins by doing:

```
window.location="chrome://plugins"
```

and you can check if this flag is available in your nwjs version by doing:

```
window.location="chrome://flags"
```